# How to create a jstree tree dynamical from a mysql database using python

Tags: jstree

I want to display the a tree format in html. Im using the following script in my html to show a jstree structure:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
        $(function() {
          $('#container').jstree({
              'core' : {
              'data' : {
              "url" : "getBOMH",
              "dataType" : "json"
             }
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

The `getBOMH` is a python method that connects to a mysql database using a stored procedure to pull the tree data. The mysql database table has a bunch of columns including "material_id", "material_name", "parent_id".

The relationship between the materials is captured by the parent_id column which stores the material_id of the parent of each material.

Im extracting the data from the database using the following python code:

@app.route('/getBOMH')
def getBOMH():

```
  con = mysql.connect()
  cursor = con.cursor()
  cursor.callproc('sp_getBOMByUser',(_user,))
  boms = cursor.fetchall()
```

Im trying to figure out a way to parse the results, and then send them to the jstree script such that it can understand the parent-child relationship of the data. Note that the data in the table is dynamic and can be changed by the user to different products with different components. So need to parse the information based on the parent_id column that determines the parent of each material.

Any ideas or tips on how to do this or where I should go for information.

Thanks

Comment: Hey use can utilize the below link and make the json as needed.
https://www.jstree.com/demo/